# Get JSON representation of request body as a string

Tags: json, go

I would like to take an arbitrary http.Request and get the body as a json string. I know this involves the json package, but it seems `json.Decode` needs a specific struct passed in by reference. How can I decode an arbitrary request body (and then stringify the result)?

```
func RequestBodyJsonString(r *http.Request) string {

}
```

Comment: you want to decode `requestbody` or `response` ?

Comment: @Eklavya request body

Comment: Why do you want to decode it, if your goal is to stringify it? Just use the un-parsed response body, since it's already a string.

Comment: @Flimzy I need a json representation of the body...

Comment: And what format is the body in to begin with?  Normally a body is already JSON, and you convert it to something else.

Comment: @Flimzy a request body can be in multiple formats, including json. Another format can be a form for example.

Comment: Yes. Which is why I'm asking you: What format is your body in to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ioutil.ReadAll` to get data in byte slice then type conversion to string to get json string

```
bytedata, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
reqBodyString := string(data)
```

An example in go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/aueayVMtQxf)

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out

Comment: I assume data should be bytedata?

Comment: Yes bytedata then type conversion into string

Comment: @istrau2 this solution gives you json string